# How to download PHP -thread safe now that Homebrew no longer support --with-thread-safety?

Tags: php, macos, thread-safety, pthreads, homebrew

I need to use PHP pthreads on Mac OS High Sierra, but Homebrew is no longer supporting downloads of PHP --with-thread-safety.

How do I get and install a thread safe version of PHP for Mac OS, Php v7.1.16 without homebrew?

If it is going to have to be some sort of manual install - does anyone have step by step directions for the mac or know where I can get instructions?

I have been looking on the internet for instructions for 5 hours now. I'm tired and can't believe that no one has any posted info on this.

Comment: have to admin that `brew` really screwed up on their php installers lately.  Might be just the right last incentive i needed to switch OS altogether.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Does your comment mean you have had a hard time finding a way to install the php-thread safe as well?

Comment: amongst others ... my dev stack is fully grounded til i can solve this, and some PECL/PEAR inconsistencies. grrrr

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I was able to get php with thread safety installed using phpbrew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get PHP 7.2.5 installed on Mac OS HighSierra with ZTS/Thread safety by using phpbrew.

Install Steps I took:

1. Downloaded phpbrew from http://phpbrew.github.io/phpbrew/ and installed with their directions. Please note at the end of the installation, they give you further instructions for setting up your ~/.bashrc to load phpbrew, look for them at the terminal.
2. Once you have phpbrew running you are ready to install php with zts by using the command below (of course you can install all of the extensions that you like by checking the installation for extension instruction)

phpbrew install php-7.2.5 +openssl='/usr/local/opt/openssl/' -- --enable-maintainer-zts --with-curl=/usr/local/

It is important to have openssl and curl already installed before installing php and you must point to their location on your computer at the install line as I have done above. You can add all the extensions you need, but you must have the openssl and curl because I had a ton of problems with installation without them. But you could try omitting.

For those of you who are using PHP ZTS so that you can go on to install pthreads --ONLY PHP 7.2 and above works with Krakjoes pthread-master which you can download and follow the installation at https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

Comment: thanks a million ! i could not figure out the `--` thingie. And (bonus) this solves a long-standing El-Capitan bizarro.